# What are the licensing rules for using cartodb's public REST API with leafletjs

Tags: leaflet, carto-js, esri-leaflet

I am currently working on a project which needs some offline mapping. I am using Leaflet.js as my base library. I have also seen that leaflet can be used with the following tile providers:

https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

The idea would be to download a minimal set of tiles from one of the sources given in the previous link in order to use them in "offline mode" (no internet connection).

I was initially planning on using cartodb because their base tiles are "clutter-free" and a good starting point to add my own annotations.

Depending on the zoom level, I would need between 1000-10000 tiles that, I will have to update every 6 months.

I am trying to figure out if I am not breaking any terms of services by accessing their public REST API (`http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`) in order to download tiles for offline viewing.

There are no API keys or any other form of identification in order to access the afore-mentioned service. Can assume that this is therefore public data (ie free)?

The cartodb terms of service are given here: https://carto.com/terms/#acceptable-use

I am not lawyer myself, but from my understanding it seems to me that it is OK to use their public REST API in order to cache tiles offline as long as I provide attribution.

Can anyone advise on this or tell how they solved a similar issue?

**Edit**:
OK answering my own question (I can't add a separate answer because my question has been put on hold). Using the carto "base maps/tiles" is free as long as you are not building any commercial apps.

If you are building a commercial app which embeds the base maps, or if you are using the maps in order to track assets (my case), you need a commercial API key. All clearly explained here:

https://carto.com/location-data-services/basemaps/

Comment: What providers are you talking about?  You don't mention any in your question.  That said, licensing questions should be asked direct to the vendor.

Comment: Also although you've been a member here for a few months I notice you haven't yet taken the new user [tour] which outlines our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Well the question is pretty clear. Can I download the tiles from cartodb, arcgis, openstreetmap etc... and cache them for offline usage. Google does not permit you to do that

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with this and any requested clarifications.

Comment: Note that four providers is four different questions  under our "Focused question / Best answer" model, and there is a "One question per Question" policy. I can't  think of a provider for which this *wouldn't* be a violation of the Terms of Service.

Comment: OK thanks for the feedback. I have tried to clarify my question.

Comment: Have you looked at section 11 of the T&C? Because downloading 1k - 10k tiles seems like you might hit some of those limits.

Comment: As you imply, interpreting T&C might be more subtle than you think. E.g., in the line of @mkennedy's comment, Carto plans specify a limit of _Map Views_, which are defined as loading tiles in a browser window, irrespective of these tiles being fetch from their server or your local cache…

Comment: You say that you're not a lawyer, which is bad, because this ***really*** needs a lawyer's review.  Getting a legal review from the Internet is worth slightly less than you've paid for it.

Comment: @BigLudinski I am still not sure you get it right. https://carto.com/pricing/ Free plan => Basemap views 75,000 / month. And I may also not be right myself, but I am not trying to play with their terms.